# Is it possible to upload an excel (.xls/.xlsx) file in a webpage and display it?

Tags: php, excel, upload, embed, xlsx

I want to upload excel (.xls/.xlsx) files in a webpage and display it as in excel. Files may contain pie charts or bar graphs. How can I do it?

Is it possible to edit the data shown in webpage from excel and save it in db or excel file?

I'm doing this project in PHP..

Edit : **My client's requirement is an interface which exactly works like excel page. They have to copy and paste excel data directly into webpage and save.
I have tried many wp plugins and php codes available in internet. But didn't meet the requirements.**

Kindly help me with your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel http://code.google.com/p/php-excel/  Those are just the top 3 from google.

Comment: Thank you friend.. I have already tried these plugins.. But still in search!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net)

```
include './Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$inputFileName = 'myExcelFile.xlsx';
$outputFileType = 'HTML';
$outputFileName = 'php://output';

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

$objPHPExcelWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,$outputFileType);
$objPHPExcelWriter->save($outputFileName);
```

That will render an xls or xlsx file to a web page

Comment: Hi.., Thanks a lot... I'm not sure whether this plugin will help me to meet the requirements..  My client is asking for something which has some functionalities of excel like editing,saving,find option,filtering,copy and paste form excel etc.. Thanks again..

Comment: It isn't an editor and doesn't have any GUI - it's a library that allows you to read/create/write spreadsheet format files from within a PHP script; but you'll still need to write all the javascript to handle editing/copypaste/etc

Comment: @markBaker i want to upload excel file and data is store it in database.And retrieve and show it in table format.How it is possible? pls help

Comment: @meenakshi - write a short page and back-end script to upload a file; store file in the database (ugly, better to store the file in the filesystem and just store the directory path to the file in the database), write a script like the above to read that file and save to php://output

Comment: @ Mark Baker I go through several code but in all the table structure is fixed.But i want something different.For eg one excel has 3 field like id,name,skills and another has 5 field etc

Answer (score 2):

this is also interesting but for java... 
http://code.google.com/p/zkspreadsheet/

i wonder if you could do some php-java bridging...

or you could try this
http://www.simple-groupware.de/cms/Spreadsheet/Home

[edit] other links collected in the meanwhile... somewhat interesting

- http://blog.dreamcss.com/dev-tools/gelsheet-php-based-web-spreadsheet/
- http://jquerysheet.googlecode.com/svn/branches/3.x/jquery.sheet.html#
- http://drupal.org/project/sheetnode
- http://www.zimbra.com/products/ss_document_spreadsheet.html
- http://www.softwaregarden.com/wkcalpha/
- https://www.zoho.com/docs/online-spreadsheet.html (not free)

[edit2]

a recent new entry:

- webodf spreadsheet viewer http://www.webodf.org/about/features.html

Comment: Interesting links - I'd been thinking about using WebSockets for a front-end spreadsheet editor but I'll be interested in trying out the groupware link